# Yii2 RestApi. Реализовать Api для обновления модели в проекте Yii2

Tags: массивы, yii2, rest

Суть задачи: Есть бд на 1c,есть бд на самом сайте. Нужно сделать так,что бы при добавлении записей в бд 1с, бд на сайте тоже обновлялась этими данными. Как я реализовал это (скорее всего через одно место, надеюсь,что знающие люди меня поправят или хотя бы подскажут в каком направлении смотреть): По запросу api стучусь в 1c и запрашиваю данные, которые преобразую в массив. Этот массив сравниваю с данными с сайта при помощи метода array_diff и в зависимости от результата запускаю updateAll с соответствующими параметрами.

```
class BrandController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\ar\Brand';

    public function actionUpdate()
    {
        $query = Brand::find();

        $f_brand = $query->indexBy('id_1с')->all();

        $brands = $query->indexBy('id_1c')->all();

        $result = array_diff($brands,$f_brand);
        if ($result!=null)
        {
            Brand::updateAll(['id_1c']);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Похоже, что то, что вы пытаетесь велосипедить, называет репликацией.

Comment: Вопрос-то в чëм?

Comment: Вопрос следующий->нужно сравнить два массива с данными (из бд 1с и бд сайта) и,если в первом есть изменения,обновить второй. Много костылей у меня получается...